# pass an function with parameters inside

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs

I have a common form with I want to handle user input and save data. but because endpoint and user type are different I should use another class to pass an save function to it.
here I have my save function :

```
const save = async ({ data, props }) => {
  const { match: { params: { userkey } } } = props;
  const { name, selected } = data;
  await rest.post(
    '/v1/distributor/role',
    { key: name, permissions: selected },
    {
      'x-distributor-key': userkey,
    },
  );
};

export default compose(withProps({ save, getPermissions }))(NewRoles);
```

with userRole came from another file and create a form and fire save function with submitting in the Form  :

```
render() {
    const { save } = this.props;
    const { permissions } = this.state;
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div className="col-md-4">
        <Form
          submit={save({ data: this.state, props: this.props })}
          change={this.change}
          nameChange={this.nameChange}
          permissions={permissions}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

here I pass save function to Form. and expect when submit clicked save function fire with `data` and `props` parameters. but according to log, save function not passing to Form in function style, it passes a promise, seems it's fired before:

```
submit={save({ data: this.state, props: this.props })}
```

how can I pass save function to submit with that parameters

Answer (score 3):

You are not passing function. Actually, you are calling the function which means you are passing the returned value of that function (which is promise) to `submit` prop. So, instead pass a function. Change

`submit={save({ data: this.state, props: this.props })}`

to

`submit={() => save({ data: this.state, props: this.props })}`